# MoviePy Vertical Text Issues

Tags: python, moviepy

Trying to create a textclip on MoviePy going vertically rather than horizontally.

Tried a couple of variations from examples I've found but I'm struggling to figure out the right syntax:

```
TextClip = TextClip.add_mask().rotate(90)
TextClip = vfx.rotate(TextClip, 90)
TextClip = TextClip.rotate(90)
TextClip = (TextClip.add_mask().fx(mp.vfx.rotate, lambda t: 90 * 
t,expand=False))
```